# SQL services wont start due to incorrect drive letter after windows restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

SQL services wont start due to incorrect drive letter after windows restore

Had a server crash, was successfully able to reinstall windows and restore the server SQL and all the necessary services were already installed.

Only problem the windows drives letters are wrong. So the services are pointed to the incorrect drive letter. I cant change the services in regedit or change the drive letter in disk management. Is there a way to do a repair in SQL add remove programs to associate's the necessary services with the correct drive letter?

Here's a example of the services
Path to executable
I:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\

only problem the actual drive letter is E:

Services that wont start
SQL SERVER
SQL SERVER AGENT
SQL Server Analysis
SQL Server Analysis Services
SQL Server Integration Services
SQL Server Reporting Services

Comment: If you reinstalled windows, why not reinstall SQL Server? Trying to manually repair SQL Server can bring up problems down the road. It is best to do fresh install of SQL Server and then restore your databases (both system and users).

Answer (score 0):

try `subst` command, maybe it'll help you ... kind of workaround though..

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Subst i: e:\' (at a cmd prompt) then you can get SQL to start, as suggested backup your data, remove SQL and re-install it with the correct path, restore your data.  That will be the best for you long term.